# Grounding metal box joining two BX cables without ground

Tags: electrical

If I have a metal handy box used to join two legacy BX armored cables that don't have a ground wire, do I need to ground that box like I would with NM cable by connecting the box with the NM ground? If yes, how?

Comment: Is this ratty old BX that lacks the internal bonding strip, or something that has the bonding strip (akin to modern AC/"BX")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install BX cable into appropriate BX clamps - and done.

While the code world is not happy with calling BX armor an adequate ground for new installs, it was considered fine when it was installed, and if the legacy cables are there, correct cable clamps correctly installed will serve as a ground connection.

Comment: You mean clamp connectors? I do have them. Will that do the job?

Answer (score 2):

If this is old armored cable, commonly reffered to as "*BX*". Then the armor was never considered an adequate grounding conductor  (at least not that I'm aware of).  A circuit wired with "*BX*" would be considered an ungrounded circuit, just like any other two wire circuit.

If you want to add a ground, you'll have to install an NEC approved ground.  If you just want ground-fault protection, you can install a GFCI device to protect the circuit.

If it's modern Type AC or Type MC cable, then you'll use the bonding strip or grounding conductor as the ground.

Comment: I don't "need to"...

Comment: BX is what's now type AC -- and when the bonding strip is present as per 320.100, AC armor can be used as an EGC as per 320.108.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel "BX" did not have a bonding strip, as it was used before equipment grounding conductors.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel updated to be more clear. I assumed if the OP was asking the question, then no bonding strip/conductor was present.